# why use com.company.project structure?

Tags: project-management, package

Does anyone know of the practical reasons for the com.company.project package structure and why it has become the de-facto standard?

Does anyone actually store everything in a folder-structure that directly reflects this package structure? (this is coming from an Actionscript perspective, btw)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Preventing name-clashes is a rather practical reason for package structures like this. If you're using real domain names that you own and everybody else uses their package names by the same role, clashes are highly unlikely.

Esp. in the Java world this is "expected behaviour". It also kind of helps if you want to find documentation for a legacy library you're using that no one can remember anymore where it was coming from ;-)

Regarding storing files in such a package structure: In the Java world packages are effectively folders (or paths within a .jar file) so: Yes, quite a few people do store their files that way.

Another practical advantage of such a structure is, that you always know if some library was developed in-house or not.

Comment: It's the same with XML namespaces. They can be arbitrary strings but most of the time are URLs that often even point to useful information (e.g. the XSD file that the namespace belongs to).

Answer (score 2):

I often skip the com. as even small orgs have several TLDs, but definitely useful to have the owner's name in the namespace, so when you start onboarding third-party libraries, you don't have namespace clashes.

Just think how many Utility or Logging namespaces there would be around, here at least we have Foo.Logging and Bar.Logging, and the dev can alias one namespace away :)

Answer (score 1):

If you start with a domain name you own, expressed backwards, then it is only after that point that you can clash with anyone else following the same structure, as nobody else owns that domain name.

It's only used on some platforms.

Answer (score 1):

Several reasons are:

- Using domain names makes it easier to achieve uniqueness, without adding a new registry
- As far as hierarchical structuring goes, going from major to minor is natural

For the second point, consider the example of storing dated records in a hierarchical file structure. It's much more sensible to arrange it hierarchically as `YYYY/MM/DD` than say `DD/MM/YYYY`: at the root level you see folders that organize records by year, then at the next level by month, and then finally by day. Doing it the other way (by days or months at the root level) would probably be rather awkward.

For domain names, it usually goes `subsub.sub.domain.suffix`, i.e. from minor to major. That's why when converting this to a hierarchical package name, you get `suffix.domain.sub.subsub`.

For the first point, here is an excerpt from *Java Language Specification 3rd Edition* that may shed some light into this package naming convention:

> #### [7.7 Unique Package Names](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/packages.html#7.7)
>
> *Developers should take steps to avoid the possibility of two published packages having the same name by choosing unique package names for packages that are widely distributed.* This allows packages to be easily and automatically installed and catalogued. This section specifies a suggested convention for generating such unique package names. Implementations of the Java platform are encouraged to provide automatic support for converting a set of packages from local and casual package names to the unique name format described here.
>
> If unique package names are not used, then package name conflicts may arise far from the point of creation of either of the conflicting packages. This may create a situation that is difficult or impossible for the user or programmer to resolve. The class `ClassLoader` can be used to isolate packages with the same name from each other in those cases where the packages will have constrained interactions, but not in a way that is transparent to a naïve program.
>
> You form a unique package name by first having (or belonging to an organization that has) an Internet domain name, such as `sun.com`. You then reverse this name, component by component, to obtain, in this example, `com.sun`, and use this as a prefix for your package names, using a convention developed within your organization to further administer package names.
>
> The name of a package is not meant to imply where the package is stored within the Internet; for example, a package named `edu.cmu.cs.bovik.cheese` is not necessarily obtainable from Internet address `cmu.edu` or from `cs.cmu.edu` or from `bovik.cs.cmu.edu`. *The suggested convention for generating unique package names is merely a way to piggyback a package naming convention on top of an existing, widely known unique name registry instead of having to create a separate registry for package names*.